# Kafka Streaming using foreachbatch failing

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, databricks

I need your help to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

We are running a pipeline that follows below path

```
Read kafka topic --> deserialize --> transform --> serialize --> Write to another kafka topic
```

but it is failing with below error on checkpoint location after 1st successful run

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 157.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 157.0 (TID 13262) (10.91.199.38 executor 5): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error reading streaming state file of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0,part=0),dir = s3://mybucket/staging/etl/tmp/delta/kafka_avro_serde_demo_checkpoints_37/state/0/0]: s3://mybucket/staging/etl/tmp/delta/kafka_avro_serde_demo_checkpoints_37/state/0/0/2.delta does not exist. If the stream job is restarted with a new or updated state operation, please create a new checkpoint location or clear the existing checkpoint location.

Code we used

**Reading from kafka topic**

```
input_df = (
  spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_server)
  .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", f"{truststore_location}")
  .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", truststore_pass)
  .option("kafka.ssl.ca.location", cluster_ca_certificate_location)
  .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
  .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-256")
  .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", "kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username='{}' password='{}';".format(consumer_username, consumer_password))
  .option("subscribe", kafka_topic)
  .option("kafka.group.id", kafka_group_id)
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
  .option("includeHeaders", "true")
  .load()
)
```

**Protobuf Deserialization**

```
#Protobuf Deserialization
options = {}
df_res_deserialized = (
    input_df.select(
      F.col("key").alias("kafka_key"),  
      from_protobuf(F.col("value"), 
        "SessionEvent", 
        binaryDescriptorSet=proto_binary_schema, 
        options = options
    )
    .alias("kafka_value"),
    F.col("topic").alias("kafka_topic"),
    F.col("partition").alias("kafka_partition"),
    F.col("offset").alias("kafka_offset"),
    F.col("timestamp").alias("kafka_timestamp"),
    F.col("headers").alias("headers")
    )
    .select("*")
```

**Writing using foreachbatch**

```
streaming_query = (
                        df_res_deserialized.writeStream.trigger(processingTime=processing_time)
                        .queryName(etl_pipeline_name)
                        .foreachBatch(micro_batch_func)
                        .option("checkpointLocation", s3_tgt_checkpoint)
                        .start()
                    )
```

**inside foreachbatch**

```
def micro_batch_func(self, micro_batch_output_df, batchId):
    for query_code, sql_query in self.microbatch_sql_queries.items():
        micro_batch_tmp_view_name = query_code
        micro_batch_sql_query = sql_query

        # micro batch dataframe used to create a tmp view
        micro_batch_output_df.createOrReplaceTempView(micro_batch_tmp_view_name)
        # SparkSession used to get micro batch sql context
        micro_batch_output_df = micro_batch_output_df.sparkSession.sql(
            micro_batch_sql_query
        )
        micro_batch_output_df.sparkSession.sql(micro_batch_sql_query)

        if self.target_kafka_serialization == "protobuf":
            print("===========Inside microbatch Protobuf=============")

            micro_batch_output_df.select(
                struct(*[c for c in micro_batch_output_df.columns]).alias("event")
            ).select(
                to_protobuf(
                    col("event"),
                    messageName=self.target_proto_schema_name,
                    binaryDescriptorSet=self.target_schema_descriptor,
                ).alias("value")
            ).write.format(
                "kafka"
            ).options(
                **self.target_config
            ).option(
                "topic", self.target_topic_name
            ).save()
```